# PHP array sort by 2nd key

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array that needs sorted by 'yes' and 'no' keys - how might this be done in PHP? Specifically I would like all yes's to be first index (there will only ever be 1 yes and many no's)

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [no] => Array
            (
                [0] => 379
            )

        [yes] => Array
            (
                [1] => 370
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [yes] => Array
            (
                [0] => 372
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [no] => Array
            (
                [0] => 377
            )

        [yes] => Array
            (
                [1] => 374
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.  What should the result of "sorting" the above array look like?

Comment: Yes posted too early - updated!

Comment: Check out [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). But what's the point in "sorting" an associative array? The indexes are not numeric. What does it matter if they appear first or second when dumping the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uksort` to sort an array according to its keys using a custom comparison function:

```
<?php
 function yesfirst($a, $b) {
  if ($a === 'yes') {
    return -1;
  } elseif ($b === 'yes') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function uksort_yesfirst($ary) {
    uksort($ary, 'yesfirst');
    return $ary;
}

$array = array(
  0 => array( no => array(0 => 379), yes => array(1 => 370)),

  1 => array( yes => array( 0 => 372) ),

  2 => array( no => array( 0 => 377), yes => array( 1 => 374))
);

$array = array_map('uksort_yesfirst', $array);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = array(
    array(
        'no'  => array(0 => 379),
        'yes' => array(1 => 370)
    ),
    array(
        'yes' => array(0 => 372)
    ),
    array(
        'no'  => array(0 => 377),
        'yes' => array(1 => 374)
    )
);

usort($ar, function($a, $b){
    $v_a = array_values($a['yes']);
    $v_b = array_values($b['yes']);
    if($v_a[0] == $v_b[0]){
        return 0;
    }
    return $v_a[0] < $v_b[0] ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($ar);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [no] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 379
                )

            [yes] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 370
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [yes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 372
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [no] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 377
                )

            [yes] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 374
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your propose is just to show 'yes' key first and 'no' keys later then try this

```
function deep_krsort(&$arr) { 
    krsort($arr); 
    foreach ($arr as &$a) { 
        if (is_array($a) && !empty($a)) { 
            deep_krsort($a); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

How ever this will change your inner depth element in reverse order